# What is the meaning of 凡属?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this word? I used to see it in a batch of examples. Most recent ones:

- 如买方提出索赔，凡属品质异议须于货到目的口岸之日起30天内提出
- 上级机关的决议，凡属要一点的，必须迅速传达

Comment: any,all,those cf.iciba：凡／副 any; all; [书]in all; altogether， 属／动
under; subordinate to; belong to; be （more at iciba）
find 100 example sentences for 凡属 at jukuu

Comment: meaning of 凡属 similar to 凡是 which seems more widely used, often interchangeable, jukuu examples may suggest 凡属 often used, as in Q, in commerce, bureaucratic language,legalese, bible translation

Comment: This second sentence make no sense to me. I guess you missed a 重 before 要

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Belonging to. What. Where. Word by word: ordinarily with regard to.

See [http://www.iciba.com/凡属](http://www.iciba.com/%E5%87%A1%E5%B1%9E)

Answer (score 1):

`凡属` is a short version of `凡是`+`属于`. Then it'd be much easier for you to understand:

- `凡是`: any
- `属于`: belongs to

BTW, This second sentence make no sense to me. I guess you missed a `重` before `要`

Answer (score 0):

凡属品质异议须于货到目的口岸之日起30天内提出
All disputes pertaining to product quality shall be submitted within 30 days starting from the date of arrival of the product at the port of destination.

凡属要一点的，必须迅速传达
 I assume  "要一点"has been defined earlier in the document. I guess it means "Priory 1".

All Priority 1 matters shall be speedily communicated.

Comment: 凡属要一点的 all relatively important ones, cf. iciba:要 [yào]
A

形
1

（重要） important; essential

extremely important

紧要

an important matter [affair]

要事

Comment: cf。＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂一点（数量）／一些（数量）２，都可以在形容词之后作补语，或者组成＂有一点、有一些＂放在形容词或动词之前，表示不高的程度。通常可以互‌​换，不过＂一点＂表示的程度更低。此时＂一＂可以省略：胖一点 长一点 简单一点 高兴一点 （一些）（一点 often lengthened to 一点儿) looking for words containing 点 corresponding to "priority" at jukuu only yields 重点， "point one" could be 第一条，
also 要点 main points; key point，第一点 １st point，to start with (see e.g. iciba)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a combination of two single Chinese characters. The former is a  pronoun equal to "everything" while the latter is a verb that is the same as the word, "possess". 
Actually many Chinese characters have their own meanings. So it is a method that phrases can be understood word by word. However, this method is useful with several weakness. Due to some idioms originated from exclusive storys, they were given to specific meanings.

Answer (score 0):

“但凡” short as “凡”，means “all of”.And “属于”short as “属”，means “belong to”.
  You could interpret this word “凡属……” as “in this case” if be followed by a clause.If it is followed by a noun，it means “one of ”.
  Sorry ，my english is not better than a child.

Answer (score 0):

translate it into English: all those that belong to